# jQuery regex selector doesn't work

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

I need to get some element by id regex. I have found some solution for that [source](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/):

```
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
        validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
        attr = {
            method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ? 
                        matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
            property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,'')
        },
        regexFlags = 'ig',
        regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}
```

Everyone claims it's working fine but when I try to run simple code `$(':regex[id,^node\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+$]')` I get an error on match[3].split saying that method does not exist. In fact I've added console.log(match) in the first line of this function and I got:

`[":regex", "regex", undefined, undefined, index: 0, input: ":regex[id,^node-[0-9]+-[0-9]+$]"]`

What do I do wrong?

Comment: _“I need to get some element by id regex.”_ – can you be a bit more specific on that?

Comment: What not clear here? I have element with id that matches specific pattern and need to access it using jquery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `[]` instead of `()` to specify the regex

```
$(':regex(id,^node\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+$)')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pxwRx/)

*I'll also advice to use it along with some other faster selectors like a class-selector or element selector or at the least using a attribute exists filter like $('[id]:regex(id,^node-[0-9]+-[0-9]+$)')*

Comment: I know that it's not very efficient but in this specific case it's the best approach for me.